# Find the JS and jQuery codes and functions behinde an event in a web page quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

When an event occur in a web page maybe a function be ran, of course if web designer has been assigned some codes to it and make require links.

But there are different ways to link the codes and events, especially when we are using a framework like jQuery! For example when we want assign a function to `Click` event of a `Button` or `Checkbox` , we can find it by different selectors and do this in the web page or in an external `JS` file and import it and....

**Now i want now what are your suggestions to find the codes under an events (for example click event on a `Checkbox`) quickly.
Which lines and where?**

I now i can discover the web site codes and pages to find it but i'm looking for a quick way and want know what is your suggestions...

Do you recommend some tools? Please explain them.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Developer Tools in your browser will help, and the search function build in

Comment: your image show the page resources, but is a way to focus on a control and find the codes linked to its events? 100% this events  registered on page load so they must be accessible some where!